# fetch count using group by on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below table where i want to fetch count of different users for different subject on daily basis.

```
id userid subject date
1  100    English  28-09-2018
2  101    English  28-09-2018
3  100    Maths    29-09-2018
4  101    Science    29-09-2018
5  102    English    28-09-2018
6  102    Science    29-09-2018
```

I tried with group by but did not get expected result.
below sql doesnt work properly.

```
select count(userid), subject, date from user_detail group by subject,date
```

Comment: In what way didn't it work?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: would you please provide exact result set

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Nonsense. `mysql> CREATE TABLE user (user SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.16 sec)`

Comment: @Strawberry yes, you're right, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get Count of unique users for a grouping of `date` and `subject`, you can use [Count(Distinct ..)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) function.

Try the following:

```
SELECT date,
       subject, 
       count(distinct userid) AS unique_users_count 
FROM user 
GROUP BY date, subject
```